# Block screensaver

Tags: screensaver

Could you provide simple approach to block screensaver and prevent locking computer.
I need this for running automation tests and I have no rights to change this on local machine due to global computer locking company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's [mouseJiggler](http://mousejiggler.codeplex.com/)

> Mouse Jiggler is a very simple piece of software whose sole function
>   is to "fake" mouse input to Windows, and jiggle the mouse pointer back
>   and forth.
>
> Useful for avoiding screensavers or other things triggered by idle
>   detection

Answer (score 0):

a windows system? I did on Windows 2008 R2:

- use notepad.exe to create c:\temp\idle.vbs
- paste code
  `Dim objResult
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  i = 0;
  Do While i = 0
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (60000)
  Loop`
- every 60 seconds, this script "press" numlock twice
- run the script `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe c:\temp\idle.vbs`

Additonal you can create a new Shortcut, paste the command line and set to "run minimized", camouflagethe icon to explorer or other stuff.