# Detect inactivity and cancel screensaver

Tags: c#, screensaver

I am making a WPF C# program. For the next stage I want to create a message that appears on the screen after half an hour of inactivity. I define inactivity as no mouse movements and no keys pressed. I have two questions for this

1) How would I trigger the message to show after half an hour of inactivity?

2) How would I cancel the windows screensaver if it is running?

So far I have looked at:

- [Block screensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354555/block-screensaver)
- [Making a screensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876738/making-a-screensaver)
- [Screensaver in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296903/screensaver-in-windows-8)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912891/dynamically-configure-screensaver-application-content
- [Interrupt an active screensaver programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864129/interrupt-an-active-screensaver-programatically)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C

You will see that frustrating most results point to creating a windows/linux screensaver rather than helping with my goal which is creating code that triggers from inactivity like the windows screensaver does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [this article on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C).

The trick was to search for "System Idle" instead of "Screen Saver Effect".

(Credit to [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092620/system-idle-detection))

Comment: Thanks @gunr2171 that really helped. The page you linked to was gone but I found many others by search System Idle. Here was the best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Not sure why the links don't work, work fine for me. Try looking at the source of my post for the true links.